# disable matplotlib toolbar

Tags: matplotlib, toolbar

Is there a way to disable/hide matplotlib Toolbar that shows up on the bottom?

I'd tried something like this:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'
```

but unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: That works for me. What backend are you using?

Answer (score 26):

Make sure to call `mpl.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'` **before** you instantiate any figures.

Comment: Doesn't work for the nbagg (`%matplotlib notebook`) backend.

Comment: Is the toolbar the thing at the top of the figure window that has the zoom/pan buttons in it, or the display at the bottom of the figure window that displays x- and y-coordinates of the cursor? Is there a separate name for these display widgets?

Comment: @Taylor I found [this block of CSS code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46735198/8508004) in  call before invoking the plot seemed to remove the toolbar when using the nbagg (`%matplotlib notebook`) backend.

Answer (score 4):

If you are in Jupyter using `%matplotlib widget` (ipympl) you can do:

```python
fig.canvas.toolbar_visible = False
```

You can also disable header and footer with:

```python
fig.canvas.header_visible = False
fig.canvas.footer_visible = False
```

Comment: YESSSS this is what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can hide the toolbar:

```
QToolBar.hide()
```

or

```
QToolBar.setVisible(False)
```

---

Obviously this will only work with a Qt backend.
To expand on this answer, given the figure fig:

First, if using Qt5:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
```

Otherwise:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui as QtWidgets
```

Then:

```
try:
    win = fig.canvas.manager.window
except AttributeError:
    win = fig.canvas.window()
toolbar = win.findChild(QtWidgets.QToolBar)
toolbar.setVisible(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on bejota's answer:

Obviously this will only work with a Qt backend.
To expand on this answer, given the figure fig:

First, if using Qt5:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
```

Otherwise:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui as QtWidgets
```

Then:

```
toolbar = win.findChild(QtWidgets.QToolBar)
toolbar.setVisible(False)
try:
    win = fig.canvas.manager.window
except AttributeError:
    win = fig.canvas.window()
toolbar = win.findChild(QtWidgets.QToolBar)
toolbar.setVisible(False)
```

Answer (score -2):

you can go to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data` ,
there you will see the file named `matplotlibrc`, open the file and 
you will find a line like:

```
#toolbar      : toolbar2# None | toolbar2  ("classic" is deprecated)
```

uncomment that line and place `None` after the colon like:

```
toolbar      : None# None | toolbar2  ("classic" is deprecated) and save the file,
```

I guess after you can disable the toolbar in graphs plotted by matplotlib.