# Matplotlib navigation toolbar is invisible

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

When I plot an image, my Navigation toolbar (zoom-in, forward, back...) is invisible. I helped myself with this link: [disable matplotlib toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942956/disable-matplotlib-toolbar). I have first tried:

`import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'toolbar2'`

And also checked if in the file itself is set as `'None'` but it is not.
Did I perhaps forget to install some packages? Even though I don't get any errors.

Is there **alternative way to zoom-in and see the coordinates of cursor**, because that is all I need.

**Edit 1**

This is the code which I am using. I copied just the part, where I use plot.

```
#___plotting part___
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'toolbar2'
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
ax.set_title(plot_titel, loc='center', fontname=font_name, fontsize=16, color='black')
ax.set_xlabel('Column number', fontname=font_name, fontsize=16, color='black')
ax.set_ylabel('Mean of raw backscatter', fontname=font_name, fontsize=16, color='black')
ax.plot(range(len(param_image)), param_image, c='black', marker='o')
ax.plot(idx1[0], param_image[idx1], c='red', mec='red', marker='o', linestyle='')
ax.plot(idx2, param_image[idx2], c='blue', mec='blue', marker='o', linestyle='')

ax.grid()
fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Comment: What is your matplotlib version?

Comment: matplotlib version is 1.5.1

Comment: Ok, then it should be compatible at least. Cannot say more, I'm not more familiar with matplotlib.

Comment: Do you have `interactive` set to `True`? `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.ion()` will do that for you temporarily, or you can modify your `matplotlibrc`.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. The `interactive` was set to `False`, so I changed it, but after running the code, nothing has changed. Therefore I also used `plt.ion()`, but it hasn't worked. Unfortunately I don't have many experiences with `plt.ion()`, so I have provided a code in Edit 1, to see if I used it in a wrong way.

Comment: What backend are you using?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what do you mean by backend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem before. uninstall it and then install it again (try to use [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) or [miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html) distribution to install). for sure after that it will work.

do not mess with `matplotlibrc`