# matplotlib does not show right and down sides of the graph

Tags: python, plot, jupyter

I am really stumped. In Jupyter, when I want to plot, it does not plot the right and down part of my plot(as you can see in the attached figure). I have NO command about it in my code. It just does not show it by default. Could you please help? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928387/jupyter-interactive-matplotlib-hide-the-toolbar-of-the-interactive-view

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter, Interactive Matplotlib: Hide the toolbar of the interactive view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928387/jupyter-interactive-matplotlib-hide-the-toolbar-of-the-interactive-view)

Comment: Unfortunately it did not solve the problem, though the interactive view is disabled, still I can not see the xticks of my graph. Do you know how to bring my plot settings to default as it was at the very first when I installed it?