# Matplotlib window opening with menubar at the top

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making a very basic matplotlib program, which currently just plots 3 points in a line. However when I show my window for some reason it generates with a weird menubar at the top, but in all the tutorials that isn't there. Is there any way to remove the menubar so that it is only the graph in the window? Is it part of a new version of matplotlib? Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,3,5]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image: Matplotlib window]

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55779944/how-to-remove-toolbar-buttons-from-matplotlib) out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [disable matplotlib toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942956/disable-matplotlib-toolbar)